# C# Serialization, alternative set of DataMember(Name=) attributes

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I'm serializing my DTO to XML messages using DataContractSerializer, however I need to support 2 XML formats, they are identical in structure but differ in element naming, so I need to support an alternative set of DataMemeber[Name=""] attributes on my DTO's. How to solve this without cloning my DTO classes? I need to support both formats at runtime, so preproccessor derectives will not suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for fine-grained xml serialization, `XmlSerializer` is preferable to `DataContractSerializer` (which is fine as a *general purpose* serializer, but is hard to take seriously as an xml serializer when it can't even handle attributes).

Secondly, `XmlSerializer` has options for this - in particalar, `XmlAttributeOverrides`. With an `XmlAttributeOverrides` you can configure the entire setup for your type at runtime, then just pass it in to the `XmlSerializer` constructor. **Important warning:** do this once and store the serializer instance, otherwise you will haemorrhage dynamic assemblies.

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides xao = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        xao.Add(typeof(Foo), new XmlAttributes { XmlRoot =
               new XmlRootAttribute("alpha")});
        xao.Add(typeof(Foo), "Bar", new XmlAttributes { XmlElements = {
               new XmlElementAttribute("beta") } });
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Foo), xao);
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("","");
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, new Foo { Bar = "abc"}, ns);
    }
}
```

with output:

```
<alpha>
  <beta>abc</beta>
</alpha>
```

Comment: The problem is that my DTO's are really "stupid" objects, they have fields, afaik XmlSerializer can't serialize fields.

Comment: @Alex if they are `public` it can; btw even "stupid" objects (meaning: simple DTOs) should still use properties.

Comment: also I'm using Interfaces for collections.. (ICollection<T>, etc), afaik XmlSerializer doesn't handle them, also XMLSerializer is slow, in short I don't like it :-) I would prefer not to use it, if I have a choice.

Comment: @Alex fine; but DataContractSerializer doesn't support what you want, so you'll need a parallel DTO

Comment: I was thinking maybe there is a way to introduce a new AltMemeberNameAttribute, and extend DataContractSerializer to make use of it.

Comment: @Alex none of which I am aware

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the possible solutions is to use alternative serializers.

For XML I have used OXM mapper for quite a while with lots of succcess: http://code.google.com/p/oxm/
Thought it require more work than just to apply attributes.